# Different width for caption and floatfoot with floatrow

Tags: captions, width, floatrow

I am using the `floatrow` package.  I would like to define a separate width for both the caption above and the `\floatfoot` below the floats.

I want the caption to span the entire width of the page, but I want the `\floatfoot` to only be as wide as the float object.

I can get both the caption and the `\floatfoot` to be the same width as the figure, but I am just not sure how to decouple the two from eachother.  I had considered using the `\RawCaption` command, but I don't quite understand how to use it.

Here is my MWE.  In this, the width of the caption and the `\floatfoot` are coupled together.  I want the caption to maintain the original width (which I believe is `\textwidth`), and I only want the floatfoot to be altered to `\FBwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\floatbox[{\captop}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
  {\caption{Selected Interatomic Distances of Protons in $\beta$-Pinene Normal Lactone}%
   \label{fig:noeDistances}}
  {\includegraphics{nOeDistances}
   \floatfoot{\textsuperscript{1}All distances reported are in \si{\angstrom}.\\
   \textsuperscript{2}Selected carbon numbering is given in cyan.}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\RawCaption` outside the `\floatbox` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\RawCaption{\caption{Selected Interatomic Distances of Protons in $\beta$-Pinene Normal actone}\label{fig:noeDistances}}\vskip\captionskip
\floatbox[{\captop}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
    {}
    {\includegraphics{nOeDistances}
    \floatfoot{\textsuperscript{1}All distances reported are in \si{\angstrom}.\\ \textsuperscript{2}Selected carbon numbering is given in cyan.}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice the `\vskip\captionskip` to obtain the default vertical separation between the caption and the image as implemented in the `floatrow` package.

I used the `demo` option for `graphicx` in order to replace the actual figure with a black rectangle; do *not* use that option in your actual code.

Comment: Wonderful thank you so much, and for such a quick response!

Comment: @JM without this additional space, the caption will appear too close to the figure; you need to use the proper value (which I can't remember right now).

Comment: Hi Gonazlo,

Sorry, I had deleted the comment, as I wasn't sure if I should be placing it in a new question or not, still learning the format of this forum here.

Do you have any suggestion of where I can look to find this value?

Thank you for the quick response, it's very appreciated!

Comment: @JM if you give me some time, I'll look the exact value up and will update my answer as soon as I can (right now I am kind of busy with other stuff).

Comment: Thank you so much.  As my first endeavor into using stackexchange, I'm really very surprised and excited at how responsive the environment is!

Comment: @JM I've updated my answer with the proper value for `\vskip`: `\captionskip`. If the `floatrow` package is not used, you will need `\abovecaptionskip` instead.