# Allow floatfoot to left-align beneath figure, but extend past right

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, margins, floatrow

I can set my `\caption` and my `\floatfoot` as separate widths, using the following example, based on the answer to my previous question:  [Different width for caption and floatfoot with floatrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64012/different-width-for-caption-and-floatfoot-with-floatrow)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\RawCaption%
    {\caption{Selected Interatomic Distances of Protons in $\beta$-Pinene Normal Lactone}%
     \label{fig:noeDistances}}\vskip\captionskip
\floatbox[{\captop}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
    {}
    {\includegraphics{nOeDistances}
    \floatfoot{\textsuperscript{1}All distances reported are in \si{\angstrom}.%
    \\ \textsuperscript{2}Selected carbon numbering is given in cyan.}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, I've found that in this case the second footnote wraps because the figure width is quite small.  The result I had intended to achieve, would be that the `\floatfoot` would be left aligned to the figure, but be able to extend past the right of the figure.

I did try setting the width of the `\floatbox` to something greater than `\FBwidth` using the `calc` package, and then use `\FBwidth*\real{1.5}`, but this predictably puts half the extra space on each side of the float.  Resulting in the `\floatfoot` no longer being left-aligned.

I've also considered manually calculating the width of the image, then setting the margins myself, something like:

```
\def\mygraphic{\includegraphics{nOeDistances}}
\newlength\graphicwidth
\setlength\graphicwidth{\widthof{\mygraphic}}
\newlength\leftMarg
\newlength\rightMarg
\setlength\leftMarg{\textwidth-\graphicwidth/2}
\setlength\rightMarg{0pt}
```

But I'm just not familiar enough to complete the idea.

Comment: I have a possible simple solution, but it is so ugly that I prefer to wait to see if someone else provides a better approach. If no better solution appears, I will post mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution I really don't like, but (as I said in a comment) I will post it since no one else has provided a better approach.

The idea is to set the `\floatbox` width to something greater than `\FBwidth` and then manually (this is the part I don't like) correcting the alignment for the `\floatfoot` material.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

% a length to store the current \FBwidh value for latter use
\newlength\mylena

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\RawCaption%
    {\caption{Selected Interatomic Distances of Protons in $\beta$-Pinene Normal Lactone}%
     \label{fig:noeDistances}}\vskip\captionskip
\floatbox[{\captop}]{figure}[1.4\FBwidth\setlength\mylena\FBwidth]
    {}
    {\includegraphics{nOeDistances}
    \floatfoot{\hspace*{0.15\mylena}\textsuperscript{1}All distances reported are in \si{\angstrom}.%
    \hfill\null\\\hspace*{0.15\mylena}\textsuperscript{2}Selected carbon numbering is given in cyan.}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works great! I got the MWE working, but not in my document. It turns out that this method and the `xifthen` or `mhchem` package do not work. I found a way to not use those packages however. Using either of those generates an error staying: "! Package calc Error: `\let ' invalid at this point." One question I do have is how do you generate the values of 1.4 and 0.15? The 1.4 is however much I need for the floatfoot to not run onto a second line of text.  However, I'm not sure about the 0.15.  Was there a way you determined that, or simply by experimenting? (I hope there is a formula)

Comment: @JM unfortunately the value `0.15` was determined by trial and error (that's why I don't like my solution). I initially thought that a factor of `1.4` for `\FBwidth` will have to be balanced with `0.2` (`= 1/2*(1.4-1)`), but this was not the case; I couldn't find an explicit formula relating those two values :-(

Comment: Not a problem.  I've found that I'm only likely to use a few various values for the `\FBwidth` modification, and that it's not too difficult to play around with the factors used then for the `\hfill`

It works great for what I need, and looks awesome too :)